# Sort QMap<QString, int>

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qmap

I have data struct `QMap<QString, int>` how can i sort it by int key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Create `std::map<int, std::string>` and push all data to it (or your `QString` and `QMap`).

or

2) Create `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> vec`,
   push all data to it and call `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());`

or

3) Use `boost::bimap`

Comment: I don't understand how `1)` will help sorting. is there any way to sort NOT A COPY, but the actual map?

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class K, class V>
struct InvertPairOf {
    std::pair<V,K> operator()(const std::pair<K,V>& p) const {
        return std::make_pair(p.second, p.first);
    }
};

void process(const QString& qm) {
    std::map<int, QString> sorted;
    std::transform(qm.begin(), qm.end(),
                   std::inserter(sorted, sorted.begin()),
                   InvertPairOf<QString,int>());
    process_sorted(sorted);  // ...
}
```